# How do I calculate age from date of birth and current date while taking leap year into account?

Tags: java

I have date of birth and can get the current date.

In java, how can I calculate someone's age while taking leap year into account?

Edit: Can I use unix timestamps and compare the difference?

Comment: Use Java 8's Time API or JodaTime [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737159/how-can-i-create-a-calculation-to-get-the-age-of-a-person-from-two-dates/29738430#29738430)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"taking leap year into account"_?

Comment: You think you don't get older on a leap year?

Comment: This is an XY question.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish that means you need to account for anything to do with leap years when determining age.

Comment: It was an interview question. I thought it was sufficient to just say that there are 365 days in a year, 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute. He asked me how I would take leap year into account. Apparently doing the way I did doesn't take leap year into account because there aren't actually 365 days in a year in reality.

Comment: @BrianTHannan if that was an interview question, my answer is: Don't start working there. Unless the correct answer was "I'd use a library for that".

Comment: You probably came up with a timeMillis calculation in your interview. The interviewer asked about leap years to make you see that this isn't accurate; you need to use a calendar of some sort to calculate age (since our age is determined by the calendar, not by the milliseconds gone by)

Answer (score 8):

As you may know that java 8 date and time API changes are inspired from Jodatime library itself, so out next solution using java 8 looks almost similar to above code sample:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1);

Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);

//Now access the values as below
System.out.println(p.getDays());
System.out.println(p.getMonths());
System.out.println(p.getYears());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1990, 12, 2);
    LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
    Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Java 8`:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(1987, Month.AUGUST, 10);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.MAY, 27);

long numberOfYears = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Great examples for using dates with `Java 8`:
[Java 8 Date Examples](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-8-datetime-api-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer has suggested, you could use `JodaTime`.

**Here's the sample code.**

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
```

Comment: Do you know how it calculates it under the hood?

Answer (score -2):

What about:

```
    Date birthDate = new Date(85, 03, 24);

    GregorianCalendar birth = new GregorianCalendar();
    birth.setTime(birthDate);
    int month = birth.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int day = birth.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();

    int age = now.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - birth.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);

    int birthMonth = birth.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int birthDay = birth.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int nowMonth = now.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int nowDay = now.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (nowMonth>birthMonth) {
        age = age+1;
    } else {
        if (nowMonth == birthMonth) {
            if (nowDay >= birthDay) {
                age= age+1;
            }
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("Now it is my " + age+ " year of life");
```

Comment: Since when is a person's age calculated in days?

Comment: Since he said that he need to take a leap years into account, so he wish the days information,

Comment: @RealSkeptic surely you don't know that, because you're way too old, at least over 5.000 (days) :D.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ask any parent

Comment: Let's assume age has to be in years and exact.