# Action Listener (JFrame) will not change the instance variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, mutators

```
public class YourAge extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField fNameTextField;
    private JTextField initialTextField;
    private JTextField lNameTextFIeld;
    private JTextField dob;
    private int age;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void setAge(int i) {
        age = i;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    YourAge frame = new YourAge();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public YourAge() {

dob.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                
                    String sdob = dob.getSelectedText();
                    int months = Integer.parseInt(sdob.substring(0,2));
                    int days = Integer.parseInt(sdob.substring(3,5));
                    int years = Integer.parseInt(sdob.substring(6,10));
                    
                    age = (int) ((2024 - years) + (0.0833*(1 - months)) + 0.0323*(27 - days));
                    
                    
                    
            }
            

        });

}
}
```

The Action Listener is in the yourAge constructor, which extends the Jframe class. In the Jframe class, there is an instance variable "age" that I want this code to change, but for some reason it is not working.

I made a "setAge()" mutator method outside the Action to implement this, but it is only working outside the Action Listener, not inside.

Comment: Maybe consider providing a [mcve].  `ActionListener` on a `JTextField` will only be triggered when you press the platform action key (typically the `[Enter]` key) - you could also have a parsing issue, so worth checking for that. I'd also recommend making use of the new `java.time.*` API to calculate the age, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737159/how-can-i-create-a-calculation-to-get-the-age-of-a-person-from-two-dates/29738430#29738430) as time isn't linear (lots of weird edge case things going on)

Comment: HI @MadProgrammer, thank you for this response, I have implemented the time API but I am still unsure of how to change the instance variable. One method I have tried is passing the variable by using a final variable but I am stuck on how to get the calculated value out of the ActionListener method. Would there be a way for me to retrieve the textfield without doing all this ActionListener stuff? Thank you

Comment: You never create a text field to assign to `dob`, so your program should fail with an NPE when you try to run it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies, I have created the textfield but have left the code out for a more concise presentation of the problem.

Comment: That makes it impossible for people to run your code, and so it makes it hard to help you.